# How to automatically evaluate certain lisp code after starting an emacsclient?

Tags: emacs, emacsclient

When starting Emacs, init.el (or .emacs.el) is evaluated. However, when starting emacsclient, no similar lisp code is evaluated.

How can I get a lisp file to be evaluated every time I open a new emacsclient?

(This would be handy for frame specific customizations.)

I assume the answer is to use some hook, but I can't seem to find the correct hook to use.

I look forward to your answers.

Answer (score 16):

You can add a function to the hook `'server-visit-hook`, which is run every time the server is called (every time you call `emacsclient`).

Comment: Apparently this hook is only called if emacsclient is passed a file list. If it is called without specifying any file, then the hook isn't run - which is annoying.

Answer (score 7):

I use the following code to automatically change the behavior of server buffers. I use it especially with the Firefox extension [It's All Text](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4125). In that extension, buffers are named according to the domain name, so you can figure out which rule to apply by using `string-match` to match the name of the file.

```
(defun server-edit-presets ()
  (cond
   ;; When editing mail, set the goal-column to 72.
   ((string-match "mail\\.google\\.com\\.[0-9a-z]+\\.txt" (buffer-name))
    (longlines-mode-off)
    (auto-fill-mode 1)
    (set-fill-column 72)
    (save-excursion
      ;; Don't know if this is necessary, but it seems to help.
      (set-buffer (buffer-name))
      (goto-char (point-min))
      ;; Replace non-breaking strange space characters
      (while (search-forward (char-to-string 160) nil t)
        (replace-match " "))))))

(add-hook 'server-visit-hook 'server-edit-presets)
(add-hook 'server-visit-hook '(lambda () (longlines-mode 1)))
```

Answer (score 5):

If you really want new frame customizations, there's create-frame-hook which takes one arg (the new frame)...

If you mean gnuclient, you can use the command-line option "-eval" to evaluate something (and then just make an alias to always eval your customizations).

Answer (score 1):

@LSW:

Try `'window-setup-hook`. This addresses the annoyance since it is called even if emacsclient is not passed a file.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that those hooks are no more, so here's the new version.

```
(add-hook 'server-after-make-frame-hook 'consult-recent-file)
```