# how to run certain elisp code after starting a new emacsclient frame?

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode, emacsclient

[For how to automatically evaluate certain lisp code **every time** starting an emacsclient, click here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040143/how-to-automatically-evaluate-certain-lisp-code-after-starting-an-emacsclient)

My problem is different. I want to write a script that opens a new emacs frame (with focus on it) (one way to do this is to run `emacsclient -c`) and then run the following elisp code in that frame.

```
(org-remember)
```

I tried

```
emacsclient -c & emacsclient -eval '(org-remember)'
```

But sometimes it just opens a new frame unfocused and then runs the elisp code, and other times, it opens a new frame focused but runs the elisp code in the old frame.

Some who knows what org-remember does might ask me why not just do this:

```
emacsclient -eval '(org-remember)'
```

but that doesn't bring focus on the old frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My version of *emacsclient* doesn't support the `-c` argument, despite [the documentation advertising it](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/emacsclient-Options.html#emacsclient-Options).

I'm not sure if there's a cleaner way to do this, but you could try using [`make-frame`](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Frames.html) and [`select-frame`](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Input-Focus.html#Input-Focus), like so:

```
emacsclient -e '(select-frame (make-frame))' '(org-remember)'
```

That will create a new frame and, in case your window manager doesn't select it automatically, grant it focus, and then execute the second command with that new frame having focus.

Answer (score 2):

How about just combining the two command lines you've already tried into one:

```
emacsclient -c -e '(org-remember)'
```

That works in Emacs 23.1.