# How can I launch emacsclient maximized from the commandline

Tags: maximize, emacsclient, maximize-window

I am wonder how to start emacsclient in a new maximized frame.

```
emacsclient -c
```

starts a new frame *but* the man page indicated no way to maximize this frame. There are no such options as `--maximized`.

*Warning* : this is no a duplicate from the post : [How do I provide a command-line option to emacsclient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363808/how-do-i-provide-a-command-line-option-to-emacsclient). Indeed, the answers of this post don't fix my issue. They use the `-F` option which seems to be documented on the man **for them** but which is not present in my `man emacsclient` (in debian sid) and the `-F` option does not work in my case :

```
$ emacsclient -c  -F "((fullscreen . maximized))"
     emacsclient: unrecognized option '-F'
     Try `emacsclient --help' for more information
```

Here is the result of `emacsclient --help` for information :

```
emacsclient --help
Usage: emacsclient [OPTIONS] FILE...
Tell the Emacs server to visit the specified files.
Every FILE can be either just a FILENAME or [+LINE[:COLUMN]] FILENAME.

The following OPTIONS are accepted:
-V, --version           Just print version info and return
-H, --help              Print this usage information message
-nw, -t, --tty          Open a new Emacs frame on the current terminal
-c, --create-frame      Create a new frame instead of trying to
                        use the current Emacs frame
-e, --eval              Evaluate the FILE arguments as ELisp expressions
-n, --no-wait           Don't wait for the server to return
-d DISPLAY, --display=DISPLAY
                        Visit the file in the given display
-s SOCKET, --socket-name=SOCKET
                        Set filename of the UNIX socket for communication
-f SERVER, --server-file=SERVER
                        Set filename of the TCP authentication file
-a EDITOR, --alternate-editor=EDITOR
                        Editor to fallback to if the server is not running
                        If EDITOR is the empty string, start Emacs in daemon
                        mode and try connecting again

Report bugs with M-x report-emacs-bug.
```

Comment: Why not just start another emacs process? Is there a particular reason you have to use emacsclient for this task? Using regular emacs on Solaris I can launch it full screen from the command-line by using the `-fs` option.

Comment: If you want to start in a maximized frame every time, you might want to try the first answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040143/how-to-automatically-evaluate-certain-lisp-code-after-starting-an-emacsclient?rq=1)

Comment: Also, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315739/how-can-i-set-styling-and-positioning-of-a-newly-created-emacsclient?rq=1) seems relevant to your post.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(fullscreen . fullboth))
```

in .emacs does the job.

Comment: Note that this causes `emacsclient` to start fullscreen. To maximize, replace `fullboth` with `maximized`.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a minimal working example from Evgeny's answer

```
  emacsclient -c -F "'(fullscreen . fullboth)"

  emacsclient -c -F "'(fullscreen . maximized)"

  alias ecx="emacsclient -c -F \"'(fullscreen . maximized)\""

  emacsclient -c -F "((width . 100) (height . 100) (left . 400))"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try using ‘-F alist’ or ‘--frame-parameters=alist’ option.

alist format is described [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Frame-Parameters.html#Frame-Parameters)

You can select width, height and font so that you'll have comfortable window size.

Comment: Excuse me, but I couldn't decrypt the abbreviation you've used (MWE). Did you mean [MEW](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Mew)?
But I guess you ask me to show you a screenshot with emacsclient opened. If so, I'm afraid I can't do that - I don't use it.

Comment: Sorry, MWE for minimal working example. That is to say a code which produces what I want (instead of indicate paths to a possible answer)

Comment: (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(width  . 90))
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(height . 40))
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "Monospace-10"))
That's the code you can find following the link I provided. Sorry if this doesn't help you.

Comment: This isn't fullscreen. I answered myself with the proper command (which is a correct MWE). But thanks for leading my to a solution (I give you the boundty).

Comment: I'm glad that it helped either way))